# How to get/set paragraph before/after spacing of list items in PowerPoint with VSTO

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, margin

I'm working on a PowerPoint VSTO addin and am needing to get at the margins between List Items.  In the PowerPoint interface, you can adjust this value by right clicking the individual paragraph and selecting paragraph and then adjusting the Before or After value in the Spacing section (for PowerPoint 2007).  This is the same place that you edit the margin between paragraphs when they're not in a list.  So on the code side, through the Shape object in VSTO, I can access valid values when they're not in a list by checking out the Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraph[index].ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore property.  When I use this property when the paragraph is in a list and the space before is something other than 0, it always has .2 as the value.  Using the Shape.TextFrame.TextRange... property doesn't help either.  What property do I need to access to get/set the actual value?